# conforming one matrix to dimensions of another

Tags: r

I have two matrices that I want to add together, but they have different dimensions.

I have a larger matrix with all possible rows & columns:

```
> m1 <- cbind(a=c(x=1, y=2, z=3, w=4), b=c(5:8), c=c(9:6), d=c(5:2)) ; m1
  a b c d
x 1 5 9 5
y 2 6 8 4
z 3 7 7 3
w 4 8 6 2
```

And a smaller matrix that has a subset of the larger matrix's rows and columns:

```
> m2 <- cbind(b=c(y=5, z=7), c=c(2, 6)); m2
  b c
y 5 2
z 7 6
```

Is there a fancy way to get the dimensions of `m2` to "conform" to the dimensions of `m1`?

What I'd like is the following:

```
> m3 <- cbind(a=c(x=NA, y=NA, z=NA, w=NA), b=c(NA, 5, 7, NA), c=c(NA, 2, 6, NA), d=c(rep(NA,4))) ; m3
   a  b  c  d
x NA NA NA NA
y NA  5  2 NA
z NA  7  6 NA
w NA NA NA NA
```

So that I can do things like this:

```
> m1 + m3
   a  b  c  d
x NA NA NA NA
y NA 11 10 NA
z NA 14 13 NA
w NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `match` on the attributes.  This will return NA when a name is not found, consequently inserting the NA rows and columns you want.

```
> foo <- function(x, y) {
      mat1 <- match(colnames(x), colnames(y))
      mat2 <- match(rownames(x), rownames(y))
      unname(y)[mat1, mat2]
  }
> m1 + foo(m1, m2)
#    a  b  c  d
# x NA NA NA NA
# y NA 11 10 NA
# z NA 14 13 NA
# w NA NA NA NA
> m3 + foo(m3, m1)
#    a  b  c  d
# x NA NA NA NA
# y NA 11 10 NA
# z NA 14 13 NA
# w NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: This is nice, gets around the `subscript out of bounds` error when I try doing `m2[rownames(m1),colnames(m1)]`

Comment: Also, I think one of the main things is `unname`.  The names will be added when you add a matrix to the result of `foo`. Otherwise, they would be ugly and have `<NA>` names.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking Richard's answer:

```
mmconform <- function(smaller, larger) { 
  result <- unname(smaller)[match(rownames(larger), rownames(smaller)),
                            match(colnames(larger), colnames(smaller))]
  dimnames(result) <- dimnames(larger)
  result
}
```

Which extends nicely for a 3d array:

```
aaconform <- function(smaller, larger) {
  result <- unname(smaller)[match(dimnames(larger)[[1]], dimnames(smaller)[[1]]),
                            match(dimnames(larger)[[2]], dimnames(smaller)[[2]]),
                            match(dimnames(larger)[[3]], dimnames(smaller)[[3]])]
  dimnames(result) <- dimnames(larger)
  result  
}
```